# How can i use file.path for List<File>?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the code below that gives me path

```
File image;
String imagename = image.path.split('/').last;
```

But how can i use it for

```
List<File> images;
```

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following to get a single file name from a specified index

```
String imageName = images[index].path.split('/').last;
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried ?:

```
ArrayList<String> imagenames =new ArrayList<>();
for (String imagename :images){
    imagenames.add(imagename);
}
```